# Simple existence proofs without bounds

Tags: logic, soft-question, arithmetic

Which is/are the most simple proof/s of an existential statement like
$$
\exists x P(x)
$$
or
$$
\forall x \exists y P(x,y)
$$
where the variables rage over the integers, such that the proof doesn't provide any information about how far is the number that is claimed to exist in the first case or how far is $y$ as a function of $x$ in the second case.

Comment: existence of inverse modulo large primes, maybe?

Comment: Which proof are you thinking about?

Comment: For all $x$ and given prime $p$, there exists a $y$ such that $xy \equiv 1($mod $p)$. The proof is using pigeonhole principle: Consider $x,2x,3x,4x,...,px$. These are $p$ different numbers, and none of them leave the same remainder mod $p$. Since there are only $p$ possible remainders, each one corresponds to exactly one remainder, so for some $y$, $yx$ leaves a remainder of $1$. Thus $y$ is the inverse of $x$, but the size  of $y$ could be anything under $p$. If $p$ is something like $97346111$, we would have trouble finding $y$ given $x$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Euclid's algorithm finds $y$ in polynomial time, doesn't it?

Comment: Somebody edited the question. Before I put my comment in there was no mention of time. But you're right. I'll try and come up with a better example.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The point is not the time required by some algorithm, the point is whether the proof provide information about how far we must go to find $y$ given $x$. In this case we know that we have a bound $y \leq px$

Comment: I know that. That's why if the prime is large then you have to search for a while, but yes, there is a bound, so my example is somewhat incorrect.

Comment: What makes you think there are proofs of those statements?  $P(x)$ and $P(x, y)$ could just be $x \ne x$.

Answer (score 2):

A silly example: given any integer $n$ and a Gödel numbering system, let $\{ n \}$ denote the Turing machine with Gödel number $n$. Let $P(n)$ be the proposition "$\{n\}$ halts on input $0$".

The halting problem is unsolvable, which means that if the Gödel numbering system is horrible, we can't determine which the first index is of a halting machine. We just know that one exists.

---

If you want something on a related question which is not quite the same:
Let $P(x)$ be the statement that $x$ is a prime factor of some large fixed semiprime $n$. (That is, $n = pq$ where $p, q$ are prime.)

Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, there is some $x$ which divides $n$, but factoring is thought to be algorithmically a very hard problem. All we really know is that there is some $x$ with $2 \leq x \leq \sqrt{n}$.

This is an example where we have a bound, but no real idea where $x$ lies within that bound.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x \exists y $ s.t. $y > x$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

If not then $\mathbb{N}$ has a largest element $\implies$ $\mathbb{N}$ is finite. Q.E.D. by contradiction.

Comment: But this provides information about the number $y$; it specifies it exactly, in fact.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens I have edited it :)

Comment: Isn't this statement just equivalent to "$\mathbb N$ doesn't have a largest element"?

Comment: Well you did ask for simple proofs :/

Comment: Ok but this seems almost like "A implies A" :)